# Update json on leaflet through d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, leaflet

I am using `leaflet` and am displaying a `json` with `d3 (vers3)` on the map.
Basically I am following this tutorial [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/).

This is my code. The first `callbackHandler` describes a method that receives information which another language sends to `JavaScript`, based on userinteraction with the website.
`pathToFile` is a link to a file (`json`) that is then loaded by `d3.json(...)`.

```
var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg"),
g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

someMethod("myName", function(pathToFile) {
    console.log(pathToFile);
    d3.json(pathToFile, function(error, collection) {
    console.log(collection);
        if (error) throw error;
            
        // Use Leaflet to implement a D3 geometric transformation.
        function projectPoint(x, y) {
            var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
            this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
        }
    
        var transform = d3.geo.transform({point: projectPoint}),
        path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

    
        var feature = g1.selectAll("path")
        .data(collection.features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
        .attr("stroke", "white")
    
        map.on("viewreset", reset);
        reset();
    
        // Reposition the SVG to cover the features.
        function reset() {
            var bounds = path.bounds(collection),
            topLeft = bounds[0],
            bottomRight = bounds[1];
        
            svg1 .attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0])
            .attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1])
            .style("left", topLeft[0] + "px")
            .style("top", topLeft[1] + "px");
        
            g.attr("transform", "translate(" + -topLeft[0] + "," + -topLeft[1] + ")");
        
            feature.attr("d", path);
        }
        console.log("1");
        });
console.log("2");
});
```

The funny part is: The first time the code is executed it works fine. My `json` gets displayed on the map as it should. However, when the first `callbackHandler` (`someMethod`) gets executed a second time (upon interaction through some user with the website), the new `json` does not get displayed on leaflet.

Thats the output of the `console.log` I included after trying to update the map:

```
  // on startup of website, the callbackHandler "someMethod" gets 
 ./some/path/toFile
 Object {crs: Object, type: "FeatureCollection", features: Array[20]}
 2
 1

 // after interaction with the website and execution of the callbackHandler "someMethod"
 ./some/other/path/toFile
 Object {crs: Object, type: "FeatureCollection", features: Array[9]}
 2
 1
```

But, the new `json` does not get displayed. Instead the old one stays.
Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I dont have a code to play around.

My hunch is:

When you first call `someMethod` the file gets uploaded and everything works fine.

```
 var feature = g1.selectAll("path")
        .data(collection.features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
        .attr("stroke", "white")
```

**Reason:**

First time `g1.selectAll("path")` runs. The selection is empty and you append path as per the data in the `collection.features` this will work.

Second time when you do `g1.selectAll("path")` it will return paths you bind data but append will **not** work.

So the problem is you need to remove old `collection.features` or need to update it.

To do that

**Option1**

```
var paths = g1.selectAll("path").data()

paths.exit().remove();//remove old data paths

var feature = paths
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
        .attr("stroke", "white")
```

**Option 2 remove all the paths**

```
var paths = g1.selectAll("path").data()

g1.selectAll("path").remove();//remove all paths

var feature = paths
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
        .attr("stroke", "white")
```

Hope this fixes your problem!

Read update/enter/exit [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for the link. I am very new to JS and d3 always makes me trouble. Option 1 does not work, option 2 does the trick. I think I understand a little more now!

Comment: With option 2 you want to change the order though.  `g1.selectAll("path").remove();//remove all paths` must come before `var paths = g1.selectAll("path").data()`

Comment: yeah you may... but it will not affect anything. The reason is that i am appending the path later on after the remove.